# Recursive problems in Python using os.walk()

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, os.walk

I'm very new to using Python (strong c# background), so I'm still learning what results I should expect from functions. I'm getting weird results creating a recursive function which will borrow down a directory structure.
I'm using the os.walk() function and it appears to me that once you borrow deep enough, the return results for the 'directories' aren't been cleared when finding an empty folder.
I"m using Eclipse as my IDE and Python 2.7

```
def CheckSubFolder( folder ):

    print "Checking folders in : " + folder;

    for (root, directories, files) in os.walk(folder):
        for folder2 in directories:
            print folder2;

        for folder2 in directories:
            CheckSubFolder( folder + "\\" + folder2);

    return;

# Code Entry
InFolder = sys.argv[1];
CheckSubFolder( InFolder );
sys.exit();
```

Here is the example directory structure that I'm using.

```
State
    -> 1
        -> 2
        -> 3
            -> 4
            -> 5
                -> 6
                -> 7
```

Here are the results that I'm being return:

```
Checking folders in : \\State
1
Checking folders in : \\State\1
2
3
Checking folders in : \\State\1\2
Checking folders in : \\State\1\3
4
5
Checking folders in : \\State\1\3\4
Checking folders in : \\State\1\3\5
6
7
Checking folders in : \\State\1\3\5\6
Checking folders in : \\State\1\3\5\7
6
7
Checking folders in : \\State\1\3\6
Checking folders in : \\State\1\3\7
4
5
Checking folders in : \\State\1\4
Checking folders in : \\State\1\5
6
7
Checking folders in : \\State\1\6
Checking folders in : \\State\1\7
```

Comment: There is no need to try to user `os.walk` recursively, as it already walks the entire directory structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) itself works recursively. Don't call it recursively:

```
def CheckSubFolder( folder ):
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(folder):
        for d in directories:
            print "folder : " os.path.join(root, d)
        for f in files:
            print "file   : " os.path.join(root, f)

# Code Entry
path = sys.argv[1]
CheckSubFolder(path)
```

Comment: Looks like this will work well enough.  I don't think I'll have as much control over it as I'd like.  It's really just a list of folder path strings.  I'd prefer more of a feel of popping to a folder you get with recursivness.  This will have to do, cheers.

Comment: @megabytes: If you want to manually search the directory, use `os.listdir()` instead. Then you can decide yourselves how to traverse the directory structure.

Comment: @megabytes: if you use `yield` instead of `print` then `os.walk()` allows you a clean separation between the code that selects filenames and the code that processes the selected names: `for name in generate_names(topdir): ...` You could get the names from a file, command-line, etc; it won't change your processing code.